# Redshift - Checking for Db Null in the where clause

Tags: amazon-redshift, where-clause, dbnull

I am trying to filter one of columns that has DB nulls. I am trying to see how could I merge the below 2 conditions in the where clause (checking for the column labelled type) as one condition.

```
select * from table
where type in ('Type_1','Type_4') or type is null
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to refactor that WHERE clause, comparing to a list of strings and checking for nulls are two different criteria.

Answer (score 2):

you can think about the value that you definitely won't see in the column, like "undefined" or "not specified" and use that value in `coalesce` function like this:

`coalesce(type,'not specified') in ('Type_1','Type_4','not specified')`

but honestly I don't see a reason in doing that - just syntactic sugar at cost of a tiny performance hit